# Xen reduce VCPU

Tags: linux, xen, vcpu

I am trying to reduce the number of VCPU on Dom0, but not understanding why its not reducing the number.

Log:

```
[2016-02-11 13:43:25 2550] INFO (XendDomainInfo:1977) Set VCPU count on domain Domain-0 to 5
```

Commands:

```
root@user:/home/user# xm list
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0  2024    10     r-----    994.1
root@user:/home/user# sudo xm vcpu-set Domain-0 5
root@user:/home/user# xm list
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0  2024    10     r-----    994.4
```

Comment: Please, check if you are using Full-virtualization (HVM). The command vcpu-set dont work with HVM (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/xm.1.html)

Comment: It does work with HVM. I am able to to reduce/increase Vcpu with xm vcpu-set but xm list is not showing the correct vcpu count. If I check lscpu it shows me the updated value. I am not sure why xm list is not showing the correct values for vcpu.

Answer (score 2):

This is a similar case where `xm list` failed to list configuration changes:

https://serverfault.com/a/484904/337307

The issue occurs because a configuration file that is generated when the VM is first created cannot be modified, it must be regenerated to have `xm list` report the current configuration.

The steps used to regenerate the file were as follows:

> 1. Shut down the VM (DomU)
> 2. Export the VM configuration to a text file with the command
>
>    `xm list -l DomU_name > vm.conf`
> 3. Use a text editor to edit file VM configuration, eg vi vm.conf
> 4. Delete the VM from Xend and re-create it using the modified config file, using the following commands:
>
>    `xm del DomU_name xm new -F vm.conf`
> 5. Start the modified VM
>
>    `xm start DomU_name`

Or you can use `xm delete` and `xm new` to generate a new entry instead of importing the modified config file as the accepted answer suggests.
https://serverfault.com/a/484832/337307

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: When I run the command I get this error: `xm delete database  
Error: Domain is not halted.
Usage: xm delete <DomainName>

Remove a domain from Xend domain management.`